# Case in where class - stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have return the following SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentsByUserId]
    @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @roleType bit
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @classId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    EXEC [dbo].[GetClassId] @userId,@classId OUTPUT

    SELECT 
        B.StudentId, 
        B.StudentName, 
        B.Description, 
        B.StudentType
    FROM 
        ClassStudents A
    INNER JOIN 
        Student B
    ON 
        B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
    WHERE 
        A.CassId = @classId
    AND 
    ( 
        B.StudentType =
        CASE 
            @roleType
            when 1 
            then 1
            when 2
            then 2
        END
    OR 
        B.StudentType =
        CASE 
            @roleType
            when 1
            then 4
            when 2
            then 2
        END
    )
```

When I run this as following

```
exec [GetStudentsByUserId] '28f95465-f30f-4b8b-cc92-d4c4e8d73273', 1
```

It returns the students with student type 1. 
And when I run this as following

```
exec [GetStudentsByUserId] '28f95465-f30f-4b8b-cc92-d4c4e8d73273', 2
```

Also it returns the students with student type 1. But I need students with type 2.

I just want to get students with type 1, 4 when I pass `roleType` as 1, and want to get students with type 2, when I pass `roleType` as 2.

Any better solutions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Why both MySQL and SQL Server tags? (Are you really using both products here?)

Comment: Just MySQL. I re edited it bro.

Comment: Well, the [dbo].[GetClassId] part looks more like sql server

Comment: You are right bro.. Its SQL server only.. :) , Sorry I am new to this part, So,  I thought both are same.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Edited :)

Comment: @Gunaseelan `@roleType bit` it will accept only `1` OR `0`

Comment: @Gunaseelan : "I just want to get students with type 1, 4 when I pass roleType as 1, and want to get students with type 2, when I pass roleType as 1." whats the difference?

Comment: @DarkKnight Copy past issue. :(

Comment: @tinka Thank you so much. If you want credits add it as answer.

Comment: Change your where clause ... AND ((@roleType = 0 AND B.StudentType IN (1,4)) OR (@roleType = 1 AND B.StudentType = 2))

Comment: @Gunaseelan i am glad your problem solved. i am happy for D.Joe

Comment: @tikna There you are.. Nice guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input parameter `@roleType` is `bit` datatype.
According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx):

> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.

But you check it on value `2` that always will be equals `1`

Answer (score 0):

Passing 2 to bit type is not possible. You need to change your where clause like below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentsByUserId]
        @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @roleType bit
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @classId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

        EXEC [dbo].[GetClassId] @userId,@classId OUTPUT

        SELECT 
            B.StudentId, 
            B.StudentName, 
            B.Description, 
            B.StudentType
        FROM 
            ClassStudents A
        INNER JOIN 
            Student B
        ON 
            B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
        WHERE 
            A.CassId = @classId
        AND 
        ( 
                   (B.StudentType in (2) and 
            and      @roleType=1)
        OR 
            (B.StudentType in (1,4) and 
            and      @roleType=0)
        )
```